# Easiest way to replace one or another string with a value

Tags: javascript, replace

Lets say I wanted to change all instances of United States or US into U.S. is there a more elegant way to do that than running several replaces:

```
function replaceUS()
{
newString = oldString.replace("United States", "U.S.");
newerString = newString.replace("US", "U.S.");
}
```

I know that if I needed to check against a huge list utilizing a loop would be helpful, but is  there a more elegant solution if I only have a few options to check for.  I know the following doesn't work, but if it did, it would be what I am trying to describe. Is there anything analogous?

```
function replaceUS()
{
newString = oldString.replace("United States" || "US", "U.S.");
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Thank you @georg, that was extremely informative.

Comment: @AmrElGarhy I agree that is related but not an exact duplicate to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a version that work with multiples occurrences.

```
var x = 'This is United States and US';
var r = x.replace(/(\bUnited States\b|\bUS\b)/g, "u.s.");
console.log(r);
```

You can also see it :

http://jsfiddle.net/s5y6msnb/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression as the first argument to "replace":

```
newString = oldString.replace(/United States|US/, 'U.S.');
```

That can get hairy pretty quickly.  You also have to handle the fact that a string may contain more than one instance of the string to be replaced.  Also, specific to your example, the string "The United States of America" turns into "The U.S. of America", which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: This solution remove only the first occurrence as you mentioned.